# error while connecting to weblogic host from a websphere client (SSL)

Tags: ssl, websphere, weblogic

what are the jars required to connect to t3s weblogic server from a websphere client?

i currently have the following jars 
    wlfullclient.jar
    cipher.jar
    webserviceclient+ssl.jar (added to the shared library)

i added weblogic.jar to my shared library but it is not getting picked up.

servers
websphere 7 to weblogic 10.3
JNDI lookup type t3s

any help in this regard will be really grateful.

thanks,
Nizam

Comment: Have you tryied connecting to your Weblogic from a standalone client? Should be almost the same configuration as WebSphere in this case is only hosting a weblogic client.

Comment: we tried connecting to the weblogic client from a standalone application. it works when i have weblogic jar in my classpath but i want to eliminate weblogic jar.what are the other jars required to enable SSL between websphere 7 and weblogic 10.3. i currently have wlfullclient.jar,wlcipher.jar and webserviceclient+ssl.jar . is there any additional jar required ?

Thanks, Nizam

Answer (score 0):

this issue turned out to be compatability between websphere 7 and weblogic 10.3 . This is a known issue . this was fixed by applying patch on weblogic 10.3 and an updated weblogic.jar.